# How do you label the horizontal and vertical axes of a table?

Tags: html

Suppose you have a table where the vertical axis is height, the horizontal axis is weight, and the table cells are the corresponding BMI. How would you label the vertical axis "Height" and the horizontal axis "Weight"?

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>140 lbs</th>
      <th>150 lbs</th>
      <th>160 lbs</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>5'4</th>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>25.7</td>
      <td>27.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>5'6</th>
      <td>22.6</td>
      <td>24.2</td>
      <td>25.8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>5'8</th>
      <td>21.3</td>
      <td>22.8</td>
      <td>24.3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use colspan and rowspan to merge cells. Practice drawing your table in excel if it helps you get an idea of what the final table would look like. In excel, you would have to merge cells to accomplish the same thing.

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4">Weight</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>140 lbs</th>
      <th>150 lbs</th>
      <th>160 lbs</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="4">Height</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>5'4</th>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>25.7</td>
      <td>27.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>5'6</th>
      <td>22.6</td>
      <td>24.2</td>
      <td>25.8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>5'8</th>
      <td>21.3</td>
      <td>22.8</td>
      <td>24.3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```